# I'm not able to connect to mysql server ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-error-1045

I installed MySql server for a class, when I attempt to connect to the server the following error message appear:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> mysql -u root -p
Enter password: hinreIsThePassword
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I also tried to connect to the server via Workbench but the same error appears (ERROR 1045 (28000))

Then I tried to follow these steps in this website: [artfulsoftware](https://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/tip.php?id=784&r=1)

but when I did the third step the following error appears:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> mysqld --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --skip-grant-tables

2020-02-23T19:33:01.744483Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000077] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value 

'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' to 'sql_mode'.
2020-02-23T19:33:01.828579Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010187] [Server] Could not open file 'C:\MySQLData\DESKTOP-1SE2QHN.err' for error logging: Permission denied

2020-02-23T19:33:01.836795Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2020-02-23T19:33:01.836867Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
```

I' using MySQL server version 8.0.19 on windows 10

Comment: try using the standard windows command window rather then the PowerShell

Comment: Hello, I uninstalled the apache service, reinsalled MySQL server and tried your suggestion and it Works, thank you, I also used a shorter password,

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled the apache service, reinsalled MySQL server and tried [RiggsFolly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310830/riggsfolly)'s suggestion in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61175481/im-not-able-to-connect-to-mysql-server-error-1045-28000#comment108223685_61175481):

> try using the standard windows command window rather then the PowerShell

and it worked.

I also used a shorter password when I reinstalled MySQL.